# Основной поток не ждет до полного выполнения анимации

Tags: android, kotlin

Как сделать так чтобы, основной поток ждал пока выполнится анимация кнопки? Переопределение OnAnimationEnd() для меня является не очень удобным решением, так как кода очень много, которые выполняются после анимации. Помогите пожалуйста, или подскажите направление!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы не хотите переопределение *OnAnimationEnd()*. То есть самый колхозный вариант.
Для этого вам нужно установит таймер.

Например ваш анимация длится где то 3 секунды,

вы можете написать так:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // здесь вам нужно написать задачу который вы хотите выполнить после 3 секунд 
        }
    }, 3000);
```